# Sorting a point array efficiently in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I need to sort a point array (a point is a struct with two `float` types - one for `x` and one for `y`) in a special fashion.

The points have to be sorted so when they are traversed, they form a zig-zag pattern starting at the **top leftmost point**, moving to the **top rightmost point**, then down to the **second leftmost point**, to the **second rightmost point** and so on.

[image: Illustration]

I need this to be able to convert arbitrary polygons to triangle strip arrays which I can then draw using GLes. **What would be the most efficient way of sorting those points**, by either using pointers (ie. passing and rearranging the pointers to the point structures) or by copying and moving the data in the structures directly?

Comment: Isn't this the same as sorting descending by y and then deciding the order for nodes with identical y?

Comment: Can you clarify your term "top-rightmost"? Do you mean "most northeasterly", "highest of the rightmost points", or "rightmost of the highest points"? (The diagram seems to rule out the second of these, but let's be thorough.)

Comment: So the points are fixed in space and you need to decide on the edges between points?

Comment: Also, is a zig-zag pattern guaranteed to exist? In your example, suppose the second point (directly connected to `Start`) is missing?

Comment: Why not use an existing converter?

Comment: @Jacob Then start needs to be connected to the next topmost right point. It's moreso about forming triangles and not zig-zags.

Comment: Why don't you just use [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation)?

Comment: @Tina Brooks: The statement of the problem makes no sense. Connecting points in 1st lefmost -> 1st rightmost -> 2nd leftmost etc. order does not generally produce a zigzag. If you have extra guarantees about your points, you have to state them. Without extra guarantees, the problem, again, makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to presenting us with an already reduced version of your original problem, believing that you are on the right path to the solution. I might be wrong, but it doesn't look like you are.

It seems (judging by your other questions) that you are ultimately looking for a *triangulation*. And, quite possibly, a triangulation of a *polygon* or *polygons* (as opposed to a set of independent points). If so, I'd suggest you take a look at some basic triangulation algorithms, like the one based on monotone decomposition. The problem you present here actually looks like a [possibly misguided] attempt to do something similar to monotone decomposition.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use qsort() with a custom compare() function that as @stefan noted, sorts descending by y then alternates (max/min) for x.

Comment: If one would care about a "true zig-zag" then alternating by max/min would be false since the position in the list matters ;-)

Comment: @Dan: How exactly would this work? How would the compare function know which alternative applies?

Comment: Obviously one wouldn't/couldn't do this in the compare function. Sorting by y and deciding for left/right afterwards is sufficient

Comment: @Gareth - I'd have to go ugly on this - use a (dare I say it?) global variable to keep track of whether to go left or right.  Daniel has a very good counter example which would make my solution less than desirable

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend you use [Delaunay Triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation). [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_planar_subdivisions.html?highlight=delaunay) (it's available in C) has a nice implementation.

Comment: The issue with complex algorithms like that is efficiency. I need something quick that can work with simple shapes (nothing over 10 points). The simplest C implementation of that algorithm I found was made up of over 16,000 lines of source code.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't solve the OP's whole problem (she wants stripping as well as triangulation).

Comment: @GarethRees The OP's question is rather unclear, this solution is really related to the question, and made me happy. I'm grateful for this answer! :-)

Comment: No. Delaunay triangulation would be a severe overkill in a situation when the original set of points already has certain convenient and nice properties. (It is just that the OP seems to have trouble formulating these properties). Moreover, I suspect that the original problem (that the OP is hiding from us) is a *polygon* triangulation  not a point set triangulation. Delaunay won't much help if that's the case. The OP seems to needs monotone decomposition followed by classic triangulation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you've given a well-defined order. For example, what order should the points be connected if they look like this:

```
*

         *
                 *
*
    *
    *
```

Comment: @Tina Brooks: The picture you posted does not match the picture requested by Daniel

Comment: @TinaBrooks in the picture that you have provided, two of the points are mixed up. The first three points from the top should get progressively farther to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend moving data from the structures directly.

The size of the point struct is only 8 to 16 bytes (16bytes if float is 8bytes). If you sort the array through pointers you are copying almost the same amount of data (Or same amount of data if float is 4bytes and 8bytes pointer on 64bit system).

I would recommend sorting through pointer if the struct is large.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to reinvent some kind of monotone polygonal chain. Some polygon triangulation methods are in short described in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) and [here](http://vterrain.org/Implementation/Libs/triangulate.html) with links to code

Answer (score 0):

You should first find the median(middle value) of the points (based on the horizontal values). This will split the set of points into left and right. Next sort the 2 sets based on the vertical value. You can then just iterate from the top from each set: take top element from left set, then top element from the right.. and so on.

To find the median there is a short algorithm based on quick-sort. But faster than quick-sort. Just recurse on the part where the median is (not on both like in quick-sort).

You should be able to do it the other way around: first sort by the vertical value and then split by the horizontal (maybe this is better when you have an odd number of points).